# mysql subtract 2 rows from each other and display in a third row

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query, which pulls out the create and modified time from the database and then changes them to unix time

```
SELECT
    tn,
    title,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) AS create_time,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(change_time) AS change_time
FROM
    ticket
WHERE
    responsible_user_id = 2
AND ticket_state_id IN (2, 3, 10)
ORDER BY
    change_time DESC
```

The results look as follows:

```
+---------+----------------------+-------------+-------------+
| tn      | title                | create_time | change_time |
+---------+----------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 7409025 | Re: otrs             |  1459861204 |  1459861263 |
| 7408967 | RINAS@cartrack.co.za |  1459765215 |  1459836797 |
| 7408935 | FW: Vod              |  1459767210 |  1459836797 |
```

How do I subtract the change_time row from the create_time rows so that the rows display the results in a new row called ave.

```
+---------+----------------------+-------------+-------------+------+
| tn      | title                | create_time | change_time | ave  |
+---------+----------------------+-------------+-------------+------+
| 7409025 | Re: otrs             |  1459861204 |  1459861263 |  59  |
| 7408967 | RINAS@cartrack.co.za |  1459765215 |  1459836797 | 71582|
| 7408935 | FW: Vod              |  1459767210 |  1459836797 | 69587|
```

Comment: MySQL `TIMEDIFF()` or simle minus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did.

```
SELECT
    tn,
    title,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) AS create_time,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(change_time) AS change_time,
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(change_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time)) AS ave
FROM
    ticket
WHERE
    responsible_user_id = 2
AND ticket_state_id IN (2, 3, 10)
ORDER BY
    change_time DESC
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. Works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(change_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) as ave
```

You can use mathematical functions and arithmetic operators to compute entries.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/arithmetic-functions.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with timestamps, you should use the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function for that. Here's an example

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(change_time) as output
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Your end query would look something like this

```
SELECT
    tn,
    title,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) AS create_time,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(change_time) AS change_time,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(create_time) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(change_time) AS time_diff
FROM
    ticket
WHERE
    responsible_user_id = 2
AND ticket_state_id IN (2, 3, 10)
ORDER BY
    change_time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose in the for loop you get create time as $createTime[$i]and change time as $changeTime[$i];Then after you echoed the values in a single row just subtract these two variables and the value will be stored in the particular row in the column ave.

Comment: Well minus can be done on the query side.I answered another way that is to minus the values as they are fetched on the loop.The values fetched are unix timestamp converted and minusing them on the loop will return an unix timestamp value